# A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: swift

This is the code to get the stuff from Parse.com:

```
func QueryImagesFromParse(){
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for oneobject in newObjects {
                        var text = oneobject["imageText"] as! String
                        var username = oneobject["username"] as! String
                        var time = oneobject.createdAt
                        var userImageFile = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                                var OneBigObject = Details(username: username, text: text, CreatedAt: time!, image: newImage!)
                                self.arrayOfDetails.append(OneBigObject)

                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                        })
                        let imageData = userImageFile.getData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to load the images and sort by upload date. When i added the line: `let imageData = userImageFile.getData()` it worked. But i get this in the output on runtime:

> 2015-09-09 16:12:56.866 Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A
>   long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.   Break
>   on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09
>   16:12:56.868 Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running
>   operation is being executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.869
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.871
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.872
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.873
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.874
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.875
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.876
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.877
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.878
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.879
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.880
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.881
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug. 2015-09-09 16:12:56.882
>   Socialize.ME[19538:977194] Warning: A long-running operation is being
>   executed on the main thread.   Break on
>   warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

Any ideas on what i can do here?